# why does Linux kernel using kobj->name[0] to determine a NULL c string?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, c-strings, sysfs

There is a question about checking c string null in Linux kernel code, could you help me, thank you!

In kobject.c, [kobject_add_internal](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.8.8/lib/kobject.c#L156) to check the name whether is NULL:

```
if (!kobj->name || !kobj->name[0]) {
    WARN(1, "kobject: (%p): attempted to be registered with empty "
                               "name!\n", kobj);
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

Why is `if(!kobje->name)` not enough?

Thank you!

Kind Regards
Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!kobj->name` is true when the string is NULL.

`!kobj->name[0]` is true when the string is empty. A C string is terminated by the character `0`, therefore a string is empty if and only if its first character is `0`.